# Hair nodes resampling - causes jitter

Tags: geometry-nodes, cloth-simulation, hair

I created some mesh lines. Simulated them with cloth. Then used geo nodes to duplicate that sim many times and used a noise to offset the duplicated sim based on the "index" to *try* to create a wool like effect. Problem is after the sim I'm trying to use the hair nodes but they keep flickering. So basically it keeps getting resampled again and again. Could someone have a solution to this? I would be much grateful!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to see the nodes. You may want to attach the blend file.  Go to https://blend-exchange.com/ and post the link back in this question.